# Monolog MongoDBHandler having BindingResolutionException error in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, monolog

I tried to create a mongodb logging channel

```
'mongo' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
    'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\MongoDBFormatter::class,
    'handler_with' => [
        'mongo' => new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017"),
        'database' => 'testdb',
        'collection' => 'testcoll'
    ]
],
```

However, im getting error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $mongodb ]] in class Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler
```

The error is only resolved when I tried to add type hint to the class constructor but obviously I can't do that since it's a package:

```
public function __construct(Client<<if I add this it works>> $mongodb, string $database, string $collection, $level = Logger::DEBUG, bool $bubble = true)
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... are you using any lib ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#monolog-formatters

Comment: @KamleshPaul no just standard `laravel` and installed `mongodb/mongodb` in composer. I think laravel is using `monolog` for logging

Comment: check that doc and use base on this

Comment: @KamleshPaul oh my god. 'mongodb' instead of 'mongo'

Answer (score 0):

So, I wanted to add here a complete answer because this post is the first one that shows up when looking for adding a mongo logger, and since the answer is buried in the comments, I wanted to add a proper answer.

The solution was to change the key `mongo` to `mongodb` in the `handler_with` array.

Leaving the working code like this:

```php
'mongo' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
    'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\MongoDBFormatter::class,
    'handler_with' => [
        'mongodb' => new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017"),
        'database' => 'testdb',
        'collection' => 'testcoll'
    ]
],
```

---

Also, you could add the following element at the same level as `formatter` to set a custom max level of nesting. This is because, by default, the document stored cannot have a depth greater than 3, and it's automatically converted to "[...]" in the log.

```php
'formatter_with' => [
   'maxNestingLevel' => 10
],
```

> Warning, in the probable event of a recursion, or an incredibly deep array, it can cause problems in mongo, because it doesn't support more than 100 levels of nesting, [source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Nested-Depth-for-BSON-Documents).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Laravel 8.x doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#creating-monolog-handler-channels):

```php
'mongo' => [
    'driver'  => 'monolog',
    'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
    'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\MongoDBFormatter::class,
    'with' => [ // <-- This is `with` instead of `handler_with`
        // 'mongodb' => new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017"), <-- This line will cause an error in `php artisan config:cache`
        'database' => 'testdb',
        'collection' => 'testcoll'
    ],
],
```

So you need to configure the service for `MongoDBHandler`. as you mentioned with a look at the handler source code the first argument is `$mongodb`.

```php
public function __construct($mongodb, string $database, string $collection, $level = Logger::DEBUG, bool $bubble = true)
```

and to be able to resolve this dependency we can configure [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-primitives):

```php
// AppServiceProvider.php

// ...

    public function register() {
        $this->app->when(\Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class)
            ->needs('$mongodb')
            ->give(app(
                \MongoDB\Client::class,
                [
                    'uri' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
                ]
            ));
    }

// ...
```